# how to make background of an activity with a image stored at local host or server?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am in a mid of my project and stuck to a problem, I am trying to make background of a image which is stored at the server or stored in a xml with image folders. I am doing so because about 15 mb of data is coverd by images in my application so i want to reduce this space by putting my images on local host (instead of drawable folder) then by parsing the data from xml i want to make it background of my activity. Please CAN SOMEBODY TELL ME HOW TO PARSE DATA FROM SERVER VIA XML HAVING LINKS OF IMAGES SUCH THAT THIS IMAGE LINK CAN BE USED TO SET AS BACKGROUND OF AN ACTIVITY...

Answer (score 1):

As far as actually setting the background from a url, you could try what this person suggests:

[LinearLayout background and images from web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229255/linearlayout-background-and-images-from-web)

You could also try making the background of your Activity into a WebView, then supplying the WebView with the url you want to load. I think that would require a RelativeLayout (or possibly FrameLayout), for z-axis layering to be possible.

As far as parsing XML, you can use the XMLPullParser or SAXParser. I'm not sure what you're really asking in regards to XML, so if you clarify your question (or add an example XML file?) I could provide additional info.

Comment: yes dear the link you mentioned is that one which i really need but I want a small code which really work. The link you mentioned gives only idea but not a program. Please do me a a favor give me a runnable code,
get a image from a link(url) and set it wallpaper. And Other Activities  must not get disturbed like textview, intents, edittext,httppost, etc. these must not get effected. In short I want to use My main xml file and at the same time i want to set background via getting image from url.
NOTE:I am not talking about Live wallpaper.